# Is there a way to send Multiple requests from web application without use of messaging protocol?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, architecture, mq

we've a following situation in application.

User navigates to a page which displays the list of 50 accounts along with additional details.
To bring that additional information online server send messages(one per account) to a MQ queue, There is a batch job which is listens to this queue and picks these messages and calls external systems via WS or EJB calls and returns the data in form of response on the queue from where online server picks it up and displays it on screen.

1. Online server send multiple messages to MQ
2. Batch job listens to this Queue
3. Picks up the message, and calls external systems accordingly.
4. creates the response and puts it back to queue
5. online server picks these messages and displays the messages on
   screen.

There are lots of redundant steps and too many points of failure in this scenario. However I understand that it has been done to achieve performance efficiency.

I would like to achieve something like this:

1) Online calls the external systems directly and gets the response.

- I could do it: in a loop for each account, that would cost me
  performance hit.
- I could open multiple threads, and fire the requests, however I am
  told opening multiple threads from a web app is a NO-NO[**can somebody
  explain why?**]

Is there any way/mechanism I could use to achieve this?

Thank you for taking time and read such-a-lengthy post.

Answer (score 1):

Re multi-threads:

For EJBs, it's not only discouraged, it's expressly forbidden by the [specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr220/index.html)
However for other areas of J2EE it can be achieved preferable by using Concurrency Utils, you ensure that your new thread is created, and managed by the container, guaranteeing that all EE services are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WorkManagers for create new threads in EJB also. See  [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/commonj/commonj.html) (it writen for WebLogic Server but can be used in every Application Server that contains **CommonJ**)